# How do you address a person's name using tellraw in Minecraft 1.3?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Just to clarify, I know how to use tellraw proplerly.

How do you address a player's name using tellraw? I want to make it like this:

> [YOU] My name is CatsAreMeow

I want it so the CatsAreMeow part can change into anyone's name. How do you do it?

Comment: `/tellraw` and signs (and a bunch of other things) all use the exact same JSON syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
/tellraw @a [{"text":"My name is "},{"selector":"@s"}]
```

to tell everyone your name. `[]` indicates an array of objects, `{}` indicates objects and then you just use key and value in quotes.

[Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Raw_JSON_text) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands&oldid=1365953#Raw_JSON_text)) is a list of all things that JSON can do.